# What could be the reason for thread to be parked at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, thread-dump

I have an executor which is responsible for consuming messages from a ArrayBlockingQueue.

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0L,
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(1),  
                r -> {
                    return new Thread(r, "Request-Queue-Drainer");
                });
```

Request-Queue-Drainer thread is in WAITING state (Though tasks are being submitted to this thread). The following is the thread-dump.

```
Name: Request-Queue-Drainer
State: WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@5b4757a2
Total blocked: 0  Total waited: 8

Stack trace: 
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What could be the reason for the thread to be in waiting status?

Comment: What do you mean, "responsible for draining messages from a queue?"  You are constructing a very ordinary looking `ThreadPoolExecutor` here.  You pass it an explicit `ThreadFactory`, but the only thing your `ThreadFactory` does differently from the default thread factory is it gives each new thread a special name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thread is waiting because the queue is empty.  That's what pool threads do:  They pick tasks from the queue and run them, and when the queue is empty, they wait.

---

Edit:  There's something else that *can* happen when the queue is empty:  The `ThreadPoolExecutor` can send in a poison pill message that causes a pool thread to die if the number of workers has been greater than the `corePoolSize` for more than `keepAlive` time units.  That won't happen in your case though because you set the `maximumPoolSize` and the `corePoolSize` to the same number (1).

---

I don't expect your `ThreadPoolExecutor` to behave any differently from the one that would be returned by `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)` except that yours can only have one pending task, and it gives the pool thread a special name.